# Spring xml ...loading variable conditionally

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jvm

My problem is as follows.

In my spring configuration, I would like to read a JVM property. Now based on the JVM property I want to pick a username value defined in some runtime property.

For example,

I have a JVM property defined `instanceId`. It can have `primary` or `secondary` string values.

Also, I have two runtime properties.

```
PrimaryAccount=123
SecondaryAccount=456
```

Now based on the jvm property value.

```
// pseudo code
if instanceId = primary 
    Bean ABC should be passed 123 in its constructor argument 

if instanceId = secondary 
    Bean ABC should be passed 456 in its constructor argument 



  I am trying this 

<constructor-arg> 
  <value>#{ systemProperties['newsAppIndexDataNode'].equals('primary') ? ${instance_primary} :    ${instance_secondary} }</value> 
</constructor-arg>
```

but I am getting error

```
Field or property '123' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at profiles, see [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml) for example

Comment: I just need a simple switch for one property. Dont want to setup explicit files

Comment: then pass constructor arg directly or user postconstruct

Comment: <constructor-arg>
      <value>#{ systemProperties['newsAppIndexDataNode'].equals('primary') ? ${instance_primary} : ${instance_secondary} }</value>
     </constructor-arg>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Java Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment environment;

   @Bean
   public YourBeanType yourBeanType() {
       final String jvmProperty = environment.getProperty("instanceId");
       if(jvmProperty.equals("primary")) {
           return new YourBeanType(123);
       }
       else if(jvmProperty.equals("secondary")) {
           return new YourBeanType(456);
       }

       return new YourBeanType(-1); //return whatever is meaningfull here, or throw an exception

   }
}
```

**EDIT**

The XML configuration would probably look like this (not exactly equivalent since id doesn't check for 'secondary'):

```
<bean class="YourBean">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="#{systemProperties['instanceId'].equals('primary') ? '456' : '123' }">
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you give me xml snippet for this ??

Comment: <constructor-arg index="0" value="#{systemProperties['instanceId'].equals('primary') ? '${PrimaryAccount}' : '${PrimaryAccount}' }">

Comment: @user1700020 In the xml you posted, you are selecting the PrimaryAccount in both cases. Also you would need to have PrimaryAccount set as a property somewhere in the xml

Comment: sorry my mistake ... 
 
<constructor-arg index="0" value="#{systemProperties['instanceId'].equals('primary') ? '${PrimaryAccount}' : '${SecondaryAccount}' }">

Comment: yest these values are being read from properties file. But I am getting extra quotes with the values